# Results of query into Dropdown menu

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

I am using the following to pull a list with value from a database.

```
$result = mysql_query("

SELECT 
ID_SOCIEDADADM as Fund_Manager_Company_Code,
DES_SOCIEDAD_CORTO as Fund_Manager_Company_Name


FROM dr_lista_rentabilidad_diaria

GROUP BY ID_SOCIEDADADM
")
or die(mysql_error());



while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
      {


  echo "<form name='country_list' method='POST' action='http://opben.com/colombia/familias-de-carteras' >
            <select name='Country' tabindex='1'>

 <option value='". $row['Fund_Manager_Company_Code'] ."'>". $row['Fund_Manager_Company_Name'] ."</option>


            </select>
        <input type='submit' value='Filter' />
    </form>"; }
```

As of right now it displays the results in there own individual dropdown menu.  I want all of them to be together.  Also how can I set one of the values as  a default selection when the page first loads?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to move out the `<select>` tag  from the `while {}`

```
 echo "<form name='country_list' method='POST' action='http://opben.com/colombia/familias-de-carteras' >";

echo "<select name='Country' tabindex='1'>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
          {
 echo "<option value='". $row['Fund_Manager_Company_Code']."'>".$row['Fund_Manager_Company_Name'] ."</option>";
    }

 echo "</select>
            <input type='submit' value='Filter' />";

    echo    "</form>";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<form name='country_list' method='POST' action='http://opben.com/colombia/familias-de-carteras' >
    <select name='Country' tabindex='1'>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value='". $row['Fund_Manager_Company_Code'] ."'>". $row['Fund_Manager_Company_Name'] ."</option>";
}
echo "</select>
        <input type='submit' value='Filter' />
    </form>";
```

For the default selection, check the array and if neccessery add attribute "selected" to the option, this makes that option the default on.

Comment: I added the selected to the option and nothing happened.  Will this automatically  submit the filter with the desired selected value?

Answer (score 0):

For "Also how can I set one of the values as a default selection when the page first loads?"

```
$defaultValue = "defaultValue";

...
echo "<option value='{$row['Fund_Manager_Company_Code']}'" . ($row['Fund_Manager_Company_Code'] === $defaultValue ? "selected" : "") . " >";
...
```